# Ошибка компилятора DCC E2149 при попытке обращения к вариантной записи как к массиву

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Имеется следующий тип:

```
type
  TRuMVector = record
    case Integer of
      0: (RuM: array [0..2] of double);
      1: (Xr,Yr,Zr: Double);
  end;

var A, B: TRuMVector;

procedure SumRuM();
begin
  A[0] := A[0] + B[0];
  A[1] := A[1] + B[1];
  A[2] := A[2] + B[2];
end;
```

В программе при компиляции ошибка:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(38): E2149 Class does not have a default property

Раньше вроде можно было?

Answer (score 1):

Текст ошибки явно говорит о том, что у рекорда нет свойства по умолчанию.

Свойства по умолчанию есть только у классов и они должны быть отмечены специальной командой:

```
property Items[Index: Integer]: TSomeItem read GetItem write SetItem; default;
```

Чтобы ваш код заработал, надо явно указать, к какому элементу идет обращение:

```
procedure SumRuM();
begin
  A.RuM[0] := A.RuM[0] + B.RuM[0];
  A.RuM[1] := A.RuM[1] + B.RuM[1];
  A.RuM[2] := A.RuM[2] + B.RuM[2];
end;
```